I keep getting this error "Cannot access offset of type string on string" whenever I try to serve dummy data to my Laravel application
I am trying to serve some data to my view. However, when i try to access the elements in my dummy array, i keep getting an error "Cannot access offset of type string on string". And I don't know what is causing this error. I'm quite new to PHP so I need assistance.
This is the data I'm trying to serve
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home', [
        'jobs' => [
            'title' => 'Influencer',
            'salary' => '790,340'
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Farmer',
            'salary' => '560,890'
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Doctor',
            'salary' => '760,881'
        ],
        [ 
            'title' => 'Engineer',
            'salary' => '1,247,122'
        ]
    ]);
});

This is the view I'm trying to populate
<x-layout>
    <x-slot:heading>
        Home Page
    </x-slot:heading>

    @foreach ($jobs as $job)
        <li>{{ $job['title'] }}</li>
    @endforeach
</x-layout>


If you would print out the structure that you've created, you'd see your typo -- the first subarray has the key jobs, then the subsequent subarrays are indexed.  Typo questions are not valued by Stack Overflow.

Earlier dupes: Passing multidimensional array to blade using controller and Passing array from controller to view in Laravel

The problem is that array of jobs is not structured properly.You need to ensure that the all array element of jobs are wrapped in main array closure(i.e. []). Use this instead.
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home', [
        'jobs' => [
            [
                'title' => 'Influencer',
                'salary' => '790,340'
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Farmer',
                'salary' => '560,890'
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Doctor',
                'salary' => '760,881'
            ],
            [ 
                'title' => 'Engineer',
                'salary' => '1,247,122'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
});


Please vote to close typo questions instead of answering them.  Please vote to close new duplicate questions instead of answering them.  Please don't ask for other users to upvote your contributions.
